# In Visual Studio Code, Reformatting create-react-app js fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I've done the very simple process of runnint create-react-app to build a react app.  Then, I open VS Code in the base folder.  I go to the app.js file and it looks normal. When I right mouse / reformat, the jsx part of the file (that is, the markup that will get converted to javascript) gets reformatted badly instead of just nesting it. I'll paste a before and after below so it's clear what I mean.

Is there some setting I forgot to set?

Before:

```
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After:

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "App" >
      <
      header className = "App-header" >
      <
      img src = {
        logo
      }
      className = "App-logo"
      alt = "logo" / >
      <
      h1 className = "App-title" > Welcome to React < /h1> <
      /header> <
      p className = "App-intro" >
      To get started, edit < code > src / App.js < /code> and save to reload. <
      /p> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are you using prettier? https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode

Comment: @azium I'm just installed prettier-vscode and it did not seem to have an effect.  right mouse / format doc still does the same thing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. And I am on a Mac.